# C Realloc Append String MySQL Connector

Tags: mysql, c, memcpy, realloc, strcat

I am attempting to loop through each database result, and have a single field from each row comma separated in a final string. I am aware that this is possible to do in MySQL alone, but I need to run functions on each result so that is not possible with the mysql only method.

Every few runs, I will get a segment fault, unwanted characters are added to the output, such as "^H^G" or Hex code (08 and 07) inside of Linux. It compiles properly, I just wish I could have consistent results. This code is inside a thread, but all variables are local to the current thread.

Final String should be the userstring char.

This is the latest code I've tried to work with.

```
MYSQL dbh;
MYSQL *dbh_p;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;
char *userstring = NULL;
char *userstring_r;
size_t userstringsize = 0;
size_t rowsize = 0;

/* Database Connect Code Here [Connects Successfully] */

if(mysql_query(dbh_p,query) == 0) {
    res = mysql_store_result(dbh_p);
    if(mysql_num_rows(res) > 0) {
        while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res))) {
            rowsize = strlen(row[0]) * sizeof(char);
            userstringsize += rowsize + 1;
            userstring_r = (char *) realloc(userstring,userstringsize + 1);

            printf("%d %d %p\n", rowsize, userstringsize, userstring_r);
            if(userstring_r != NULL) {
                /* Where the Issue Is */
                userstring = userstring_r;
                strcat(userstring,row[0]);
                strcat(userstring,",");
            }else{
                free(userstring);
                printf("Error With Realloc\n");
                mysql_thread_end();
                pthread_exit(NULL);
            }
        }
    }
    mysql_free_result(res);
}else{
    printf("Query Error: %s\n",mysql_error(&dbh));
}
```

-- EDIT --
Output:

```
9 10 0x7fe5f4014d90
14 25 0x7fe5f4014d90
9 35 0x7fe5f4014d90
11 47 0x7fe5f4014d90
... (same format and pointer value);
*** glibc detected *** ./pthread: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00007fe5f4014d90 ***
```

This is the result even when I limit the threads to only 1.

Thank you for any help, or possible issues. I don't require full code, just tips / hints and possible fixes. I have tried strncat, memcpy, and changing various sizes without any luck.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong at first glance. Could you add some tracing (i.e. `printf` statements!) to find out what it's doing, for instance `printf("%d %d %p\n", rowsize, userstringsize, userstring_r);` just before the `if` statement to confirm that it's allocating the new string properly.

Comment: I added the printf line, and updated the output.

Comment: I changed the max threads to 5, and increased userstringsize +2 instead of +1 and it seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I know what's wrong:

The first time `userstring` is allocated, it isn't initialised to being an empty string!  Basically `strcat` has been putting the new data wherever it finds the first `\0` byte, which could be anywhere.

You need to somehow check whether it's the first time, and initialise it.  Something like:

```
if (userstringsize == 0)  // First time
{
    userstringsize += rowsize + 1;
    userstring_r = (char *) malloc(userstringsize + 1);
    strcpy(userstring_r, "");  // Initialise to empty string
}
else
{
    userstringsize += rowsize + 1;
    userstring_r = (char *) realloc(userstring,userstringsize + 1);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I did set an int to check if malloc yet instead of going by userstringsize. But either way, works great. Thank you.